# Same regex have different results in Java and Python

Tags: java, python, regex

Java Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001";
        String p = "Value = (.*?), ";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()){
             System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
             System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
             System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Java code's output:

```
$ java RegExpTest 
-0.525108
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:487)
        at RegExpTest.main(RegExpTest.java:15)
$
```

Python code (in Interpreter):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("Value = (.*?), ", 'X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001;')
['-0.525108', '7.746691', '5.863008']
>>>
```

So, why is **Java unable to match** all the occurrences of the match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a **group** for a java match is a capturing bracket.

Your regex only has one set of non-escaped (ie capturing) brackets, the `(.*?)`.

Group 1 contains the value that gets matched.

**There is no group 2** because there is no second set of brackets in your regex.

In the java example, you want to loop through all *matches*, and print `matcher.group(1)`.

```
while ( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Note the `while`, which will loop through all matches and tell you group 1 from each.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `java.util.regex.Matcher.find` attempts to find the next value that matches, not all the values that match. Change `if` to `while` and you should get the result you are looking for.

```
...
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using it wrong.

`matcher.group()` returns the values of the various capturing groups **within a single match**. You only have one capturing group (i.e. one set of parentheses in your pattern).

`matcher.find()` is the method that returns the next match, if you call it repeatedly. Usually in a while loop, e.g.:

```
    while (matcher.find()){
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).